# Easily working on a json object

Tags: c#, json, xml, object, serialization

I'm deserializing (or parsing) a json string to a c# object (using Json.NET) and getting a JObject. I want to iterate all the properties with the key "bla", in the same way iterating all xml elements that named "bla" with XElement.Elements("bla").

If it's not possible, I would like to deserialize my json string into a c# object, and work dynamically and recursively on my deserialized json object (my json string can have lists / arrays that can have objects of 2 types.
In the end after editing my object (changing values and removing or adding properties)  I need to serialize my object back to a json string. 
Which is the best and easiest way to use json serializing and deserializing?

my Json looks like this:

```
{"Families":{"Family":[{"propA":"dhsj", "propB":"dhdisb"}, {"propA":"krbsbs", "propC":"ksndbd", "propD":"odndns", "Families":{"Family":[....]}}, {"propA":"dhsj", "propB":[{"propA":"dhsj", "propB":"dhdisb"}, {"propA":"krbsbs", "propC":"ksndbd", "propD":"odndns", "Families":{"Family":[....]}}, {"propA":"dhsj", "propB":"fghfgh"}]}]}
```

in conclusion, the json value is a json object that it's value is a list/array, the list/array can contain 2 "types" of objects, and one of these types also has a property which it's value is a json object that it's value is a list/array, and it goes like this recursively. sometimes the value of one of the props of the type that doesn't have a property which it's value is a json object that it's value is a list/array, can be a list/array itself, that can contain only 1 type of the two mentioned.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Did you look at the methods in `JObject`? They do exactly that.

Comment: I didn't find a method of JObject that is similar to iterating XElement.Elements("bla") which gives me every element that is named bla.

Comment: I tweaked my answer to fit your JSON, iterate recursively to N-levels and add properties dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a strongly-typed object, you can deserialize to a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

And then just use it as a dictionary:

```
myObject["Property"] = value;
```

Or

```
foreach(var propertyKey in myObject.Keys)
{
  // do something with each property
  Console.WriteLine($"{propertyKey} = {myObject[propertyKey]}");
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fCOJma)

You can serialize it back after you are done

Comment: A JObject is an dictionary, so you even need to change that part.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I didn't know that, but makes sense

Answer (score 0):

For JSON like this:

```
var json = @"{
    ""Families"":{
        ""Family"":[
            {
            ""propA"":""Top""
            },
            {
            ""propA"":""Top.Lower"",
            ""Families"":{
                ""Family"":[
                    {
                        ""propB"":""propB value""
                    },
                    {
                        ""propA"":""Top.Lower.EvenLower"",
                        ""Families"":{
                        ""Family"":[
                            {
                                ""propA"":""Top.Lower.EvenLower.EvenLower""
                            }
                        ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            }
        ]
    }
}";
```

Do something like this:

```
//calling code makes use of "dynamic" to make things clean and readable.
dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var allPropAValues = GetPropAValues(parsedJson);
//**** NOTE: this has our extra property ****
var jsonWithExtraStuffProperty = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson);

//recursive function that reads AND writes properties
public static List<string> GetPropAValues(dynamic obj)
{
    var propAValues = new List<string>();

    //**** NOTE: the use of an added property ****
    obj.ExtraStuff = new Random().Next();

    //if we have a propA value, get it.
    if (obj.propA != null)
        propAValues.Add(obj.propA.Value);

    //iterate through families if there are any. your JSON had Families.Family.
    if (obj.Families != null)
        foreach (dynamic family in obj.Families.Family)
            propAValues.AddRange(GetPropAValues(family));

    return propAValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My json looks more like this:

```
{"Familys":{"Family":[{"propA":"dhsj", "propB":"dhdisb"}, {"propA":"krbsbs", "propC":"ksndbd", "propD":"odndns", "Families":{"Family":[....]}}]}
```